# what would cause lack of movement in the gas pedal, causing slow acceleration?

Tags: fuel-system, automatic-transmission, hyundai

I have a 2002 Hyundai Elentra. Until yesterday every thing was fine. Yesterday I noticed the car was not accelerating normally.  I also noticed my gas pedal basically had almost no movement. No strange noises, the transmission seems to be shifting correctly.  The problem seems directly linked to the accelerator.

Comment: Does the gas pedal physically feel stuck? Do you have a code reader, even the cheaper ones have live data you can use to verify the throttle position sensor reading.

Comment: 2002 Elantra has a sensor based throttle, so no cables or anything that could physically make the pedal stuck. Is there perhaps something lodged in there?

Comment: Could be a car mat stopping movement.

Comment: or snow and ice if you are in a cold country

Comment: I'm with @HandyHowie - Check to ensure there's nothing blocking the pedal itself.

Comment: I don't think any of these questions are going to get answered.